# How to select a key: value pair in string format used in a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, object, key

I want to select length, but it's in string form. Something along the lines of attribs.length, but returned nothing.

```
attribs: {
    "length": ""4"",
    "nightride": "null"
}
```

I've tried splitting it and rejoining it but either way I don't get what I want.
I've also tried attribs[length] and attribs["length"] but to no avail.

Here is the major chunk it is from:

```js
{
    places: [
{
    city: "Boise",
    state: "Idaho",
    country: "United States",
    name: "Elk Meadows",
    parent_id: null,
    unique_id: 1637,
    directions: "&quot;From Boise's north end (at the intersection of Hill and Bogus Basin roads), travel north up Bogus Basin road about 16.5 miles.the pavement ends at lower (main)parking lot near Bogus Creek Lodge. Proceed on the Boise Ridge Rd. Where the sandy surface turns to pavement as it leavesthe main ridge rd.and splitsright, up through a series of switch backs to the Pioneer Lodge milage starts here",
    lat: 43.764,
    lon: -116.10324,
    description: null,
    date_created: null,
    children: [ ],
    activities: [{
        name: "Elk Meadows",
        unique_id: "1-118",
        place_id: 1637,
        activity_type_id: 5,
        activity_type_name: "mountain biking",
        url: "http://www.singletracks.com/item.php?c=1&i=118",
        attribs: {
            "length": ""4"",
            "nightride": "null"
        },
        description: "ride east up behind Pioneer Lodge past the tennis courts on your left. the double track becomes more defined",
        length: 4,
        activity_type: {
            created_at: "2012-08-15T16:12:35Z",
            id: 5,
            name: "mountain biking",
            updated_at: "2012-08-15T16:12:35Z"
        },
        thumbnail: "http://images.singletracks.com/2010/11/Elk-Meadows-on-the-Ranier-0.jpg",
        rank: null,
        rating: 3
      }
    ]
 },
```

And this is my angular attempt to get that data:

`{{ result.activities[0].attribs["length"] }}`

Comment: Use `JSON.parse`, `var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString); alert(obj.length);`

Comment: doesn't seem to be a valid json with `""4""`

Comment: that's not string form, that's invalid form

Comment: I thought the same thing, but it came like that from an API.

Comment: `it came like that from an API` - I see what you have now

Comment: the value of attribs.length is actually `"4"` - when you display it, it shows ""4"", but the actual value is three characters `"4"` ... to verify, console.log(attribs.length.length)

Comment: What you posted is neither valid JSON nor valid JavaScript. What exactly is that? You said you tried `attribs.length` but where does `attribs` come from and what is its value? The least you can do is provide a complete example.

Comment: *"but obviously that won't work."* What exactly does "won't work" mean here? How would it not work?

Comment: this "code" that you are posting - is it text content, a javscript object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if attribs is an actual javascript object and you want the numeric value of attribs.length

```
var x = parseFloat(attribs.length.replace(/"/g,''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `length` property has an extra set of quotes around it, you can use `JSON.parse` to parse it into a string.

```
JSON.parse(obj.attribs.length);
```

And to convert that to a number, use `parseInt()`. So it all becomes:

```
var length = parseInt(JSON.parse(obj.attribs.length), 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an invalid JSON. JSON should always be either a single **array** or a single **object**.

That's a proper JSON:

```
{
    "attribs": {
        "length": "4",
        "nightride": "null"
}
```

So, you can:

1. Write to the suppport of your API provider or stop using this API. That's a proper solution in 99% of cases.
2. Do some really bad hacks. I wouldn't recommend doing this in any case. However, that can solve a problem. Just something like this:

   ```
   .done(function(data) {
        data = "{" + data.replace("\"\"", "\"") + "}";

       var obj = JSON.parse(data);
       alert(obj.attribs.length);
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Alright everyone! I'm embarrassed for not seeing this before, but two key:value pairs further down the object response from where I was looking,

`attribs: {
    "length": ""4"",
    "nightride": "null"
},`

there was another key:value pair of distance in the standard value format that we all know and love:

`attribs: {
"length": ""4"",
"nightride": "null"
},
description: "ride east up behind Pioneer Lodge past the tennis courts on your left. the double track becomes more defined",
length: 4,`

emphasis on the

`length: 4,`

So of course, I directed my notation to that point.

Jaromanda X had the most direct, and in my opinion, clean/precise/accurate answer, so he takes the check.